# Eclipse SWT Browser Displays Reversed Hebrew

Tags: java, html, eclipse, swing, swt

I am using JDK 1.8.0_201 on Windows 7 with Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.2). I also have Microsoft Internet Explorer 11.0 installed. My java *Swing* application embeds a SWT [Browser](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fbrowser%2FBrowser.html). My java code writes a plain text file that contains Hebrew text in "visual order" and saves it with a *html* extension. I then set the URL for the `Browser` to point to the HTML file I just created. When I run the application, the `Browser` displays the Hebrew in reverse order. Using an English example, instead of displaying the word *Hotel*, it displays *letoH*. Here is the HTML...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO8859-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      body{font-family:"Miriam Fixed"; font-size:12px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>
      my Hebrew content
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the java code to write the file

```
java.io.PrintWriter pw = new java.io.PrintWriter("filename.html", "windows-1255");
pw.println("<html>");
// remainder of "println()" calls to create content as shown above
pw.println("</html>");
pw.close();
```

Finally, when I run my java application, I explicitly set the *file.encoding* property in the java command like so...

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

I'm guessing it's something in the configuration of my computer but I don't know what and I'm hoping someone can point me in the direction of where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not performed exhaustive tests, but nonetheless, so far, the following change to the HTML has resolved the problem. I added tag `bdo` as a sub-element of the `pre` tag, i.e.

```
<pre>
    <bdo dir="ltr">
        my Hebrew content
    </bdo>
</pre>
```

Note that this was **the only change**. All other code is **exactly** as it appears in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is that in `<pre>` tag everything is "visual order"

Normally the browser render Hebrew with "logical order".

I suggest trying the following:

1. Replace the `<pre>` tag with `<div>` tag.
2. Play with [`dir="rtl"` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp) in the `<div>` or `<pre>`.
3. Make user the encoding of your saved code is  UTF-8.

Comment: Regarding point 3, are you saying that in the code that writes the text file, I should replace `windows-1255` with `UTF-8` ?

Comment: yes. make sure you java code is saved in UTF-8 always.